# Chronyc equivalent for ntpdate -q

Tags: linux, ntp, chrony

According to ntpdate and chronyd man pages

**In ntpdate -q**     : Query only - don't set the clock.

**chronyd -q** : When run in this mode, chronyd will set the system clock once and exit. It will not detach from the terminal.

Is there any alternative command in chronyc to the following command, "query only without setting the clock"?

```
ntpdate -q pool.ntpserver.org
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **-Q**
> This option is similar to the -q option, except it only prints the offset without making any corrections of the clock and it allows chronyd to be started without root privileges.