# ntpdate unavailable on CentOS8

Tags: yum, centos8, ntpdate

I want to install ntpdate as usual on CentOS8.
However, it is not available:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5) (GCC)) #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 17:20:08 UTC 2020

# yum install -y ntpdate
Last metadata expiration check: 2:21:14 ago on Mon 11 Apr 2022 07:39:43 PM CST.
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
No match for argument: ntpdate
Error: Unable to find a match: ntpdate
```

Besides, I also find `links` `lynx` unavailable.
Is there any way to install ntpdate on CenOS 8 ?

Comment: `ntpdate` has been deprecated for quite a while since `ntpd` already has the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat stopped packaging ntpd as of EL8, replaced with [chrony](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red-hat-enterprise-linux/8/guide/6c230de2-39f1-455a-902d-737eea31ad34#_be3da94a-69e5-4622-8826-dbf884fc31af).

[`chronyd -Q`](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089999/chronyc-equivalent-for-ntpdate-q) will query for the offset and quit. Use  `-f` option to provide a config file with different NTP servers.

Other useful commands: `chronyc sources -v`  or `chronyc sourcestats -v` will show details on configured sources.

---

Text browsers for CentOS Stream 8 are for some reason in the powertools repo. (But lynx is in Stream 9 AppStream for reasons I don't understand.)

```
  dnf --enablerepo=powertools list elinks lynx
```

When you know a package exists, but are unsure of which repo it might be in, there are search engines like [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=lynx). Keep in mind repos are of varying quality and care to avoid conflicts, [CentOS wiki has strong opinions on repos](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

Comment: But how to use chrony, say, calibrate the time to a host like `time.windows.com`?

Comment: `server time.windows.com`  in chrony.conf like any other NTP source.  However I personally do not like Windows time service as it appears to still not have IPv6 in the year 2022.

Comment: The main use of ntpdate is to do the initial sync with a remote NTP server like this:
`# ntpdate 10.247.19.254`
and this response does not explain how to replace this in CentOS 8, so it should not be condidered an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the response from @JohnMahowald `ntpdate` is not included in RedHat Based distros starting with CentOS/EL 8 as all the client NTP functionality (service and command line tools) has been repaced by `chrony`.

The main use of `ntpdate` was the initial testing and sync with a remote server like this:

```
# ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
13 Apr 12:38:54 ntpdate[29547]: adjust time server 190.64.134.53 offset 0.008546 sec
```

As long as I know there is not an exact equivalent command for this in EL8, but something similar can now be accomplished by using `chronyd` like this:

```
# chronyd -q 'server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst'
...
2023-04-13T15:39:48Z Initial frequency -13.600 ppm
2023-04-13T15:39:53Z System clock wrong by 0.003503 seconds (step)
2023-04-13T15:39:53Z chronyd exiting
```

And then you can configure your servers in `/etc/chrony.conf` start the `chronyd` service and do an initial quick sync with the following command:

```
# systemctl restart chronyd
# chronyc -a makestep
200 OK
```

For more details see: [How to resynchronize with chrony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730407/how-to-resynchronize-with-chrony)